# How to get changelog since last build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build

I need to include my release notes in a gradle variable.

How to get changelog since last build in Jenkins, so that I can use them in my gradle variable

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Below line in content section of Editable Email Notification will give the output of changes from the last build and changes from last successful build.

```
${CHANGES}
```

`${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS}`

Comment: Can I use this directly in a gradle file or write it in a property file and read from there ??